# importing a simple string in index.tsx causes full .ts file to get bundled with the main bundle during build time

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack, babeljs, code-splitting

Technology used:
React
Typescript
Webpack
(Essentially an ejected create-react-app as we plan to move away from CRA)
Lazy loading at each route (react-router)

We've been diagnosing a large main bundle file and as we started removing dependencies from the index.tsx we noticed something interesting.  When importing a string const from a utility .ts file to src/index.tsx, the entire utility file would become part of the main bundle - instead of maintaining proper code splitting a just bring in the string itself.

If I remove that import of the string, the utilities file gets allocated to a separate chunk file which gets loaded when needed.

Anybody have any insight as to what may cause such an issue?
Should I be focused on webpack/babel/tsconfig?  Possibly circular dependendencies elsewhere in the code which may be making it confusing for webpack?

The imports/exports are written as such

```
export const SOME_STRING = 'some_string';
```

...

```
import {SOME_STRING} from '/utils/someutilfile.ts';
```

Comment: That's how modules work. Code splitting and chunks are based on an analysis of the dependency graph as traceable by module imports. If you have that many things in your utility module to the point that it's actually a problem for startup time, you should refactor that module so it's not a damn mess.

Comment: Okay - I do agree its a damn mess :).  However, I thought that if you are just importing the string, then that's all it would bring in.  Those utility functions are eventually used but are used by things behind lazy loaded components.  I thought webpack was smart enough to know to only bring the string into the main bundle and split off the rest of the exported utility functions to a chunk used by the lazy loaded  components.  Am I way off here in my understanding?

Comment: One other thing to clarify.  This is a react client side SPA.  So it's more about initial page load time versus startup time.  Just don't want this to get confused with a node.js server or something along those lines.